# O que faz o "%u"?

Tags: c, string

Estive fazendo um exercício de uma lista sobre strings e pesquisei exemplos. Um dos códigos era este:

```
/* strlen example */

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
 
char szInput[256];

  printf ("Entre com uma frase: ");

  gets (szInput);
  
printf ("A frase com que vc entrou tem %u de caracteres",(unsigned)strlen(szInput));
 
 return 0;

}
```

Eu gostaria de entender o que faz o `%u` e a linha de comandos seguinte, `(unsigned)strlen(szInput)`.

Aliás, esse código é [desse site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

`%u` é o equivalente ao `%d`, mas ele aceita números sem sinal, o `u` é justamente de `unsigned`. Então ele foi usado para corresponder com o resultado final estabelecido na expressão que será impressa.

Aí vem a questão porque ele usou `unsigned` para converter (*cast*) do resultado de `strlen()`. Eu não sei, poderia ter usando um simples `int` que dava na mesma, e aí poderia usar o `%d`.

`strlen()` retorna um valor do tipo `size_t`, então para imprimir um número inteiro com ou sem sinal ele precisa de um *cast*.

Mas você poderia ter usado `%zu`, ou até `%zd` e não fazer o *cast*, que é algo muito melhor. O `z` indica justamente que está aceitando um tamanho em vez de um inteiro.

[Documentação do `printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

[Documentação do `strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Cada especificador de conversão tem um tipo correspondente de argumento de resultado definido na especificação C. As diretivas de conversão `%u` e `%d` realmente aceitam as mesmas entradas, como você observou, mas o argumento correspondente a `%u` deve ser do tipo `unsigned int*`, não `int*`. Ou seja seu exemplo deve ser corrigido como:

```
unsigned int u;
int d;
sscanf ("- 2", "% u", & u);
sscanf ("- 2", "% d", & d);
```